# What is 'TCP out-of-order' and 'TCP port number reused' issue?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, wireshark

I am sending HTTP requests from IP_ADDR1 to IP_ADDR2. I observed that HTTP requests are not reaching to application level. When I take wireshark logs I noticed some issue at TCP level. What are these issue? when this occurs ? How to get rid of this? Attaching the Wireshark snapshot here.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, Did you resolved this? If yes, then how, please tell. As, I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 6):

'TCP port number reused' means that it saw a successful connection handshake, then the client sent another SYN packet with the same port numbers. If the client hadn't already acknowledged the SYN-ACK, this would have been reported as a retransmission. But since it did acknowlege the SYN-ACK, it shouldn't need to retransmit the SYN. This could mean that something on your network is duplicating packets.

'TCP out-of-order' means that the packets aren't being received in the order that their sequence numbers indicate. It might be a side effect of the duplicate packet that's causing the reused port number error -- that may be resetting the sequence numbers back to the beginning of the connection. Because otherwise it looks like the packet is in order; an HTTP command should be the next thing after the connection handshake.

Comment: Can you tell me, what can cause duplicating packets ?

Comment: Maybe a malfunctioning switch? Do you see the duplicates if you capture packets on the client machine?

Comment: My server is sending HTTP requests to 2 different clients. This issue is seen for every HTTP request sent on client 1. It is working perfectly for client 2.

Comment: Do you see it if you do the capture on client 1? Is the path from client to server the same for both clients?

Comment: yes, I see it when i did capture on client 1. Path from client to server are different. Both client are situated in different cities.

Comment: If you see it on the client, it's an issue with the client's TCP/IP stack. It shouldn't resend a packet if it has received the acknowledgement for it.